# Android - setOnkeyListen method how does it work with EditText?

Tags: android

I create a dialog window in an activity, then I put the buttons in this dialog window and listened to them. However, I want to listen to android device found in the back button. and dialog.setOnkeyListen method I used for it. I have put the program by executing dialog window EDITTEXT not enter data into the field. So when I add code to the setOnkeyListen I can not enter data into the EditText field. I hope you know what I mean

Comment: Kindly show us some `code` and frame your question properly!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please explain your question correctly with some code.

Comment: sorry , i wrote again.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to set the OnClickListener for a textview here is an example hope this helps:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
              // Code you want to execute on the click goes here
        }
    });
```